# At a basic level, what does eval-parse do in R?

Tags: r

I have seen references to the use of eval-parse in a loop or apply function, but I am still unclear on how to use it. To help beginners like me understand it, can someone explain why the first section below (without eval-parse) works, and the second one (with it) doesn't? Is this the type of thing eval-parse is used for? Thanks!

```
myfunc <- function(x){
    cat("Current x:", x, "\n")
    cat("Current index in myvec:", "\n")
    print(which(myvec == x))
}

myvec <- c("Larry", "Moe", "Curly")

lapply(myvec, myfunc)



myfunc <- function(x){
    cat("Current x:", x, "\n")
    cat("Current index in myvec:", "\n")
    print(which(eval(parse(text = x)) == x))
}

myvec <- c("Larry", "Moe", "Curly")

lapply(myvec, myfunc)
```

Comment: The short answer is, you should try not to use `eval(parse(text = ...))`, ever.  And in fact there is no call for it in your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval(parse(text = "Larry"))` is the same as typing `Larry` directly into your R terminal.

```
> "Text"
[1] "Text"
> eval(parse(text = "Text"))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Text' not found
> Text = 1:10
> eval(parse(text = "Text"))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It essentially allows you to call objects by their name in a character string. It's useful inside functions where you don't know which object you'll need yet, although most experienced R users find that storing data in a `list` eliminates most needs for `eval(parse(...))`

Comment: Might be useful to note for the sake of completeness that `parse()` returns an expression and `eval()` evaluates the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `expression`

```r
expression (1 + 1) ;
expression (1   +   1) ;
expression (1+1) ;
# same out: expression(1 + 1)
```

and

```r
expression (1 + 1) |> eval () ;
# out: [1] 2
```

same as just `1 + 1`.

And it have *Dynamic scope*. You can make a `expression (a + b)` and use it in a environment where have the `a` and `b` named object. Just different with the *Lexical scope*.

And, we can also get an `expression` by `parse`:

```r
"1 + 1" |> parse (text = _) ;
# same as: expression(1 + 1)
```

And, functions are also expressions, so, more funny thing:

```r
(expression (\ (x) x) |> eval ()) (0)
(expression (\ (x) x) |> eval (expr = _)) (0)
(parse (text = "\\ (x) x") |> eval ()) (0)
# both of them out: [1] 0

(data.frame (fs = c("\\(x) x", "\\(x) \\(y) x + y"))$fs [1] |> parse(text = _) |> eval ()) (1) ; # means just a 1
(data.frame (fs = c("\\(x) x", "\\(x) \\(y) x + y"))$fs [2] |> parse(text = _) |> eval ()) (1) (0) ; # means 1 + 0
```

Just a toy. Don't use it always, the dynamic scope always make chaos.

### about scope

```r
a = 1

closuresa = \ () a 

localscope = \ (a) a

localscope (2) # 2
closuresa () # will out 1 no matter where to use it. that's the Lexical scope.

localeval = 
\ (expr) \ (a) \(b)
expr |> eval () ;

localeval (expression (a + b)) (3) (4) # 7
localeval (expression (a - b)) (3) (4) # -1
localeval (expression (a - x)) (3) (4) # will error because there's not a `x` exist

# it only can use the name that exist in its scope. that's the Dynamic scope.
```

Take an analogy ... *Lexical scope* is likely with *Lambda Calculus*, but dynamic scope is just like some *bash playing* ...