# Search for specific line in R function body

Tags: r

I wish to "copy and modify" a function at a specific point in its body. Currently, what I have is

```
nearest_psd <- function(mat) {

  ed <- eigen(mat)
  eigvecs <- ed$vectors
  eigvals <- ed$values
  eigvals[eigvals<0] <- 0
  
  eigvecs %*% diag(eigvals) %*% t(eigvecs)
}

nearest_pd <- nearest_psd
formals(nearest_pd)$pdeps <- 1e-08
body(nearest_pd)[[c(7,3)]] <- quote(pdeps)
```

, so that `nearest_pd` is a copy of `nearest_psd`, except for the line `eigvals[eigvals<0] <- pdeps`.

However, the line number (7, in this case) is hard-coded, and I would prefer to have a robust way to determine this line number. How can I search for the line that contains the expression `eigvals[eigvals<0] <- 0`?

Comment: Ideally you wouldn’t modify the copied function but instead modify the original function to make it generic by adding the necessary parameters. In your situation, hard-coding isn’t a bad solution — in fact, it’s essentially necessary: how else would you guard against other, unpredictable changes in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `identical` to compare two expressions; that way, you can identify and replace the expression in question:

```
to_replace = vapply(body(nearest_pd), function (e) identical(e, quote(eigvals[eigvals < 0] <- 0)), logical(1L))
body(nearest_pd)[to_replace] = list(quote(eigvals[eigvals < pdeps] <- pdeps))
```

However, this is no more readable, nor more robust, than your code: in both cases you’re forced to hard-code the relevant information; in your code, the indices. In mine, the expression. For that reason I wouldn’t recommend using this.

… of course you could instead use an AST walker to replace all occurrences of `0` in the function’s body with `pdeps`. But is that better? No, since `0` could be used for other purposes. It *currently* isn’t, but who knows, once the original function changes. And if the original function can’t be assumed to change, why not hard-code the new function entirely? That is, write this:

```
nearest_pd <- function (mat, pdeps = 1e-08) {
    ed <- eigen(mat)
    eigvecs <- ed$vectors
    eigvals <- ed$values
    eigvals[eigvals < pdeps] <- pdeps
    eigvecs %*% diag(eigvals) %*% t(eigvecs)
}
```

… no need to use metaprogramming just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you want.

```r
nearest_psd <- function(mat) {
  
  ed <- eigen(mat)
  eigvecs <- ed$vectors
  eigvals <- ed$values
  eigvals[eigvals<0] <- 0
  
  eigvecs %*% diag(eigvals) %*% t(eigvecs)
}


nearest_pd <- nearest_psd

formals(nearest_pd)$pdeps <- 1e-08


nearest_psd_body <- body(nearest_psd)


# Find the string we a re looking for and replace it ...
new.code <- gsub("eigvals[eigvals < 0] <- 0",
                 "MY_NEW_CODE",
                 nearest_psd_body, fixed = TRUE)

# Buidling the function body as a string.
new.code <- new.code[-1] # delete first { such that ...
new.code <- paste(new.code, collapse = ";") # we can collapse the remaining here ....
new.code <- paste("{", new.code, "}", sep = "", collapse = "") # and then wrap the remaining in { }

# parse returns an expression.
body(nearest_pd) <- parse(text = new.code)
```

See [At a basic level, what does eval-parse do in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887422/at-a-basic-level-what-does-eval-parse-do-in-r) for an explantion of `parse`. Or [In programming, what is an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443801/in-programming-what-is-an-expression) what an expression is.

Comment: This is a bad solution: performing (brittle) string substitution is an entirely unnecessary conceptual detour, R allows doing the same thing purely using symbolic modification. Furthermore, I strongly doubt that this solution is actually any more robust than OP’s hard-coded replacement.